# Access iCloud Folder with Swift (macos Command Line Interface)

Tags: swift, macos, command-line-interface, icloud

Using a CLI program with Xcode running on macos, i'm trying to get the url of my iCloud home directory "/Users/JeanNicolas/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs" without hardcoding it.

In a CLI I cannot add iCloud capabilities.

Here my code example:

```
import Foundation
let fm = FileManager()

let pathHardcoded = "/Users/JeanNicolas/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"
let iCloudURLRoot = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
let iCloudHardcoded = URL(filePath: pathHardcoded)


print("iCloud Directory with forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: ", iCloudURLRoot)
print("iCloud Directory hardcoded: \(iCloudHardcoded)")
```

Terminal output:

```
iCloud Directory with forUbiquityContainerIdentifier:  nil
iCloud Directory hardcoded: /Users/JeanNicolas/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

[image: Capability Window]

See GITHUB [Zipping](https://github.com/Fahrenberg/Zipping/tree/main)